# CDN vs S3 at same region, then what is the use of CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, cdn, system-design

If my video contents in `aws-s3` a specific region, say `ap-south-1`(Mumbai, India).
My all video stream clients from India only, outsider of this country clients are not allowed to access those contents(controlled by application business logic).

In simple words, all Indian clients are the closest to the `ap-south-1`(Mumbai, India) region.

**In this specific scenario, what is the benefit to use CDN here?**

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc), emphasis mine:

> ##### Asia
>
> ###### Edge locations:
>
> **Bangalore, India** (3); Bangkok, Thailand (2); **Chennai, India** (4); Hong Kong, China (3); **Hyderabad, India** (3); Jakarta, Indonesia; **Kolkata, India** (2); Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia (2); **Mumbai, India** (4); Manila, Philippines; **New Delhi, India** (5); Osaka, Japan; Seoul, South Korea (4); Singapore (4); Taipei, Taiwan(3); Tokyo, Japan (16)
>
> ###### Regional Edge caches:
>
> **Mumbai, India**; Singapore; Seoul, South Korea; Tokyo, Japan

CloudFront has **6 edge locations** all over India, that could bring content even closer to your user. Whether that matters depends on your latency requirements. Aside from that, you can use CloudFront for DDoS protection and you can deploy a Web Application Firewall there as well as edit content on the fly using Lambda @ Edge. You can also add/modify headers, do origin failover, HTTP -> HTTPS redirect and other things.

If you need all of that depends on your use case.